# read() different output of text file

Tags: python

The results of this code:

```
!/usr/bin/python
from sys import argv
script, file = argv
apertura = open(file,'r')

for a in apertura:
    print(apertura.read())
```

is:

```
quarta quinta
sesta
settima
ottava
nona
```

I'd like print the whole file using read(). The code above skips some lines. Why?

The file content is the following:

```
prima seconda terza
quarta
quinta
sesta
settima
ottava
nona
```

Comment: Could you please explain better what seems to be your problem? You want to print each line in the file? Or print each word in file on separate line?

Comment: I'd like print the whole file using read(). The code above skips some lines. Why?

Comment: You can't both iterate over the file and `.read()` it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing two methods of reading the file.

```
for a in apertura:          # this reads in the first line of the file
    print(apertura.read())  # this reads the remainder of the file in one chunk
```

So the first line of the file is never printed.

You can iterate through the file line by line like this:

```
for a in apertura:
    print(a)
```

You can also use a context manager to make sure the file is closed afterward

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sys import argv
script, file = argv
with open(file, 'r') as apertura:
    for a in apertura:
        print(a)
```

If you really want to read the file using `.read()`, the code is slightly simpler, but uses a lot of memory in the case that the file is large

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sys import argv
script, file = argv
with open(file, 'r') as apertura:
    print(apertura.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

To print the entire file:

```
!/usr/bin/python
from sys import argv
script, file = argv
apertura = open(file,'r')
print apertura.read()
```

or shorter:

```
!/usr/bin/python
import sys
print open(sys.argv[1]).read()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for word in apertura.read().split():
    print (word)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for line in apertura.readlines():
    print line
```

This should work.

Answer (score -1):

with open('C:\Users\33382\Desktop\pf.txt','r') as f:
     lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
     print line